# How to handle an unexpected character while parsing JSON data

Tags: json, macos, powershell, parsing

I am running into a problem with my script. I keep getting this error:

```
Conversion from JSON failed with error: 
Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: H.
Path '', line 0, position 0.
```

I have been looking for any information online but cant seem to find anything helpful. Im not able to share the json data coming through, but its just a big generic brick of data.

```
$headers = @{
Authorization = $bearerToken}

$param = @{
Method = "GET"
Uri = fooURL
ContentType = "application/json"}

$result = Invoke-WebRequest @param -Headers $headers
$result = $result | Select-Object -ExpandProperty RawContent | ConvertFrom-Json

foreach($key in $result.Resources.PSobject.Properties){
if($key.userName.Value.StartsWith($nrUserName)){
$id = $key.id.Value
 }
}
$id
```

This is my simple little script, the error is coming from the last pipe (ConvertFrom-Json). Also another bit of info, this script does not work on my macOS machine but did work on my coworkers windows machine. Any help would be appreciated!

I originally just tried rewriting the script in hopes it was just something i messed up, but i also implemented a try/catch but i need the code to still run and it'll just error out and not give the results needed.

Comment: I think we **do** need to see some of that data, but... Are you sure you should convert the `RawContent` and not the `Content` of $result?

Comment: I was editing the script from my boss essentially and i asked the same question, i was told to leave it as RawContent. I'll have to ask if i can share some of the data, alot of it is personal keys and id's to access some infrastructure.

Comment: Nevermind your boss. Did you try `Content`? BTW. Where does variable `$nrUserName` come from? Are you aware that the `.StartsWith()` method is case-sensitive?

Comment: i just tried content, it give us different data that is not relevant to what we need. that variable comes in at the top of my script, i forgot to throw it in when i originally copied it over to here, and i do know it is case sensitive i figured id try it instead of using `-eq`.

Comment: Maybe you should try [Invoke-RestMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod) on this and if you want case-insensitive, replace `.StartsWith($nrUserName)` with `-like "$nrUserName*"`

Comment: Have you installed PowerShell on your MacOS machine? If not, you can't run PowerShell scripts. But that's probably not an issue with Windows.

Comment: I tried `Invoke-RestMethod` already, it didn't work for our use case actually. We don't necessarily need it to be case sensitive, I was just trying `.StartsWith()`.

I do have powershell installed, i used homebrew to get it up and going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`RawContent` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.commands.webresponseobject.rawcontent?view=powershellsdk-7.2.0#microsoft-powershell-commands-webresponseobject-rawcontent) is the "Full response content, including the HTTP status line, headers, and body." So it starts with the status line which starts with the word `HTTP`.

The error message you're getting says that the first character (line 0, position 0) is an `H`, which is invalid. That's to be expected if you try to pass the RawContent through a JSON parser, because a JSON value cannot start with `H`,

JSON values will normally start with a `[` (if the value is an array) or a `{` (if the value is an object). It's also legal for the value to be a number (which starts with a digit or a minus sign), or to be a string (which starts with a `"`), or to be one of the special values `true`, `false` and `null`, always written in lower-case. That makes a total of 17 possible first characters. `H` is not on this list. (Technically, JSON streams can also include whitespace -- space, carriage return, linefeed or tab -- and PowerShell's `ConvertFrom-Json` tool accepts comments starting with `//`. But still no `H`s.)

In short, `RawContent` cannot be correct, and if you're actually getting a JSON object back from that request, you don't need `-ExpandProperty` at all, because converting the response object to a string will give you exactly the string you want to feed into `ConvertFrom-Json` (at least, as I understand it). But you should check to make sure you're actually getting real JSON back from the request.

Note that using the `-ContentType` option in the request is pointless, because that option is used to describe the content *sent with the request*. `GET` requests don't have any content; the request is fully described by the headers. `-ContentType` should be used with `POST` and `PUT` requests, since there is almost always content sent with them. If you need to tell the remote server that you want JSON (and it doesn't just assume that from the extension at the end of the URL), you should create an `Accept` header with the value `"application/json"`.

But before you try any of that, start by looking at what is actually being returned by the webserver. Is it JSON? Does it contain JSON embedded in something? Or it is in a completely different format?

Comment: Thank you for your response, it was very knowledgeable. Whats being returned seems to be a JSON object, the only way to get the data we need is to use `RawContent`. When using content it provides data that is not needed to use, which is an array of numbers. If we didn't use `Expand` none of the data we need would come through, so it seemed like the only option at the time. 

Also I'm still new to most of this, so I am trying to learn the best practices as I go. I apologize if some of it was redundant!

Comment: Just wanted to say thank you for all of the help! Removing `RawContent` actually solved it.